# Integral of two terms involving Erf function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, error-function

I was solving [another problem](http://kuing.infinityfreeapp.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=6676), and it remains to prove the following integral:
$$
\int_0^{\infty }\left(3{\exp \left(-2t \right)\over t}\operatorname{erf}^2(\sqrt t) -\frac{\sqrt\pi}2{\exp \left(-t \right)\over t^{3/2}}\operatorname{erf}^3(\sqrt t)\right)dt=\frac{\pi}4
$$
Can somebody give me a hint?

Thank you very much.

Best regards.

Comment: What is that problem? We need to know your context so that the answers would satisfy you.

Comment: @KamalSaleh Ok. I have added a hyperlink.

Comment: Okay, that is good. But how did that integral bring you to the one in the OP?

Comment: @KamalSaleh I multiplied by a constant $\frac4\pi$.

Comment: [This representation for $\operatorname{erf}^2(\sqrt t)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.7#E5) may be useful for attacking the first term in the integral

Comment: The integrand of the original volume integral is equal to $\nabla^2[-\tan^{-1}(r)/(2r)]$, where $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. Perhaps this could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\frac\pi4\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^4+\sqrt{\pi\over t}e^{-t} \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^3\right)'=3{\exp \left(-2t \right)\over t}\operatorname{erf}^2(\sqrt t) -\frac{\sqrt\pi}2{\exp \left(-t \right)\over t^{3/2}}\operatorname{erf}^3(\sqrt t)$$
Evaluating the limit
$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac\pi4\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^4+\sqrt{\pi\over t}e^{-t} \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^3=0+0=0$$
and$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac\pi4\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^4+\sqrt{\pi\over t}e^{-t} \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^3=\frac\pi4\times1^4+0\times1^3=\frac\pi4$$
So the integral is $\pi\over4$